# Mongodb aggregation and date manipulation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Consider a collection which contains documents with a date and a count field :

```
{ _id: ObjectId("..."), date: ISODate("..."), count: 3}
```

I would like to query the count by week, so I have to group the data by a date truncated to the beginning of the week. 
But it seems there is no way to achieve that with the mongodb aggregation framework.

I was expecting to be able to do something like this (`$dateOfWeek` is a date operator I imagined to truncate the date at the beginning of the week) :

```
db.data.aggregate( [ {$project : { date: {$dateOfWeek: '$date'}, count:1}, 
                     { $group: {_id:'$date', count: {$sum: '$count'}} ])
```

But I didn't find a suitable date operator to do it.

I know I can do it with mapreduce but it would be so much more elegant to have a date operator rather than writing javascript code.

Comment: Have you tried using the [`$week`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/#_S_week) operator?

Comment: Interesting, the `$week` operator is ok for grouping, but then I have to transform it to a date. Maybe I can do that after the query. Btw thank you, this is a solution.

Comment: Can you provide the desired output format?